# Battery Alternator and Starter Fine but have to jump start car

Tags: electrical, buick, lacrosse

I have a 2012 Buick Lacrosse  A few days ago it wouldn't start and appeared to be the battery or related issue. I just started it, ran it for a while, then turned it off and restarted it just fine.  Well a few hours later it wouldn't start again.  I jumped it a second time and took it to Autozone to be tested; the battery, alternator, and starter were all said to be fine.  I replaced the key fob battery and nothing. I checked the fuses and they're all fine too.

So basically the car doesn't have power for ANYTHING, the key fob won't lock/unlock anything, and I can't push the brake down to put the car in neutral ... but the car will start and work fine when jumped.  What could the problem be?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: when your car is being jump started, the bypass happens at the vehicle's cable connections. Today's connections have multiple "layers" for more than one wire to be attached. Even those are being bypassed with a jump start. Maybe the entire connector should be carefully and thoroughly cleaned and reassembled?